# How do I calculate the matrix exponential of a sparse matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to find the matrix exponential of a sparse matrix:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

I can calculate this using `scipy.linalg.expm`, but it is slow for larger matrices.

```
from scipy.linalg import expm

S1 = expm(b)
```

Since this is a sparse matrix, I tried converting `b` to a `scipy.sparse` matrix and calling that function on the converted sparse matrix:

```py
import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy as np

sp_b = sp.csr_matrix(b)
S1 = expm(sp_b);
```

But I get the following error:

```
loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type csr_matrix which has no callable exp method
```

How can I calculate the matrix exponential of a sparse matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`scipy.sparse.linalg.expm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.expm.html) for your sparse matrix instead of [`scipy.linalg.expm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html).

```py
import scipy.sparse as sp
from scipy.sparse.linalg import expm
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
sp_b = sp.csr_matrix(b)
S1 = expm(sp_b);
```

Note: As you found, defining your matrix as a [CSR matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) gives the warning *"SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve is more efficient when sparse b is in the CSC matrix format"*. To get rid of this, you can do as the warning suggests, and define a [CSC matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html) if that makes sense for your application:

```
sp_b = sp.csc_matrix(b)
```

Comment: What about the following warning? How should I change the minimal example to get rid of it? SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve is more efficient when sparse b is in the CSC matrix format
  warn('spsolve is more efficient when sparse b '

Comment: change the `b = sp.csr_matrix(b)` to `b = sp.csc_matrix(b)`